# Defining JPA simple relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Iam a little bit confused by the JPA relationship definitions for my case and could use some help to make it correct. Even if it seems so easy, I run in diffrent errors all the time.

examplary:

```
@Entity
public class Person 
{
  ...
  @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}) // cascade what?
  private List<Attribute> attribs;     
}

@Entity
public class Attribute 
{
  @Id
  private Integer id;
  ...
}
```

All Persons can have same Attribute and so on.

The point is that Person should be able to cascade Persist/merge Attribute without generating duplicates.

As I said, its seems so easy, I just got stuck cause diffrent Exceptions I meet. And the right direction to "fix" the right config :)

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

OK, its seems that its a ManyToMany relationship. Even if One Person can have an Attribute only once? But a diffrent Person can have that too.
But now I have this cascading persist/merge problem.

eg:

```
Person a = new Person();
a.add(new Attribute(1));
a.add(new Attribute(2));

repo.save(a); //worked and persists Attributes

Person b = new Person();
a.add(new Attribute(1));
a.add(new Attribute(2));
a.add(new Attribute(3));

repo.save(b); //Error: IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity ..Attribute..  are being merged. Detached ..Attribute..
```

Same happens if just want to add a new Attribute to Person a. On which I have to send the whole list of existing Attributes additionally to the new one.

Comment: You have to use @ManyToMany

Answer (score 0):

These annotations are only necessary if there is a link to another entity (Table) or to another class (Bean).

For exemple if you have another entity call "Address" there is different case :

If a Person is delete you should use cascade to delete his Address too.

If a Person can have one or more Address you should use OneToMany.

If many person can have many Address you should use ManyToMany.
You can use him by default.

It is a kind of bond between classes Bean.

Comment: Sounds clear. So its a @ManyToMany in my case. Now how do I cascade? Since I want Persist and Merge(cause duplicates) but dont remove if someone else still have this Attribute. My guess was: `@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH}, orphanRemoval=true)` But orphan removal seems not possible on ManyToMany And got a IllegalStateException: Multiple representations on duplicates.

Comment: You're right if you have a ManyToMany orphan removal is not possible. Is it the only bean you have ? I meen Person ? If it is the only one you can make some functions and call them in the program. Unfortunatly, JPA don't fix all the exceptions of specifics demands.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply add a new attribute with the same identifier. You need to add the existing persistent instance:

```
Attribute a1 = new Attribute(1);
Attribute a2 = new Attribute(2);
Attribute a3 = new Attribute(3);

//an existing instance
Attribute a4 = entityManager.getReference(Attribute.class, 4);

Person a = new Person();
a.add(a1);
a.add(a2);

repo.save(a); 

Person b = new Person();
a.add(a1);
a.add(a2);
a.add(a3);
a.add(a4);

repo.save(b);
```